# Changes in dependent modules cannot be seen in other module in Maven Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I am working on a multi module project with m2eclipse. I set the maven to take care of resolving workspace dependencies. But when I make change on, say, service module, change is not visible on other modules immediately. If I make new method in Service layer, it is not visible in WebApp layer. Sometimes even *Run/maven install* and *refresh* and *Project/clean* and *Maven/Update Dependencies* doesn't work. Can someone give me an idea on this problem?

My project structure looks like as follows:

**parent module**

```
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>einvites-parent</artifactId>
<modules>
  <module>myproject-common</module>
  <module>myproject-domain</module>
  <module>myproject-service</module>
  <module>myproject-web</module>
</modules>
```

**service module**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject-service</artifactId>
```

**web module**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject-web</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>myproject-web</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: `But when I make change on, say, service module, change is not visible on other modules immediately.` This should work, and it does for me. If you can provide a pom allowing to reproduce the problem, I suggest reporting an issue.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent It works for me too, but i think at build time he needs to build service before he build web

Comment: @org.lie.java: Why? That's the whole point of enabling *workspace resolution*, Eclipse "perma compile" should make things transparent for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is supposed to work; and it does for me. I'm really not sure if this will fix the problem but could try to change your POM to use a `SNAPSHOT` version i.e. something like `1.0-SNAPSHOT` (you're supposed to use `SNAPSHOT` versions anyway for modules under active development).

By the way, there are lots of unnecessary and redundant stuff in your POMs. They should look like this:

**service module**

```
<project>
  ...
  <parent>
    <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <!--groupId>com.myproject</groupId--> <!-- no need, you inherit it -->
  <artifactId>myproject-service</artifactId>
  ...
</project>
```

**web module**

```
<project>
  ...
  <parent>
    <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <!--groupId>com.myproject</groupId-->  <!-- no need, you inherit it -->
  <artifactId>myproject-web</artifactId>
  <!--version>1.0</version-->  <!-- no need, you inherit it -->
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>myproject-web</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId> <!-- use the built-in properties instead -->
        <artifactId>myproject-service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version> <!-- use the built-in properties instead -->
        <!--type>jar</type-->  <!-- no need, that's the default -->
        <!--scope>compile</scope--> <!-- no need, that's the default -->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I changed version back to -SNAPSHOT and cleaned the POM as you suggested and restarted and cleaned everything. Now it seemes working but I am not sure which one fixed my problem - POM version name or redundant tags or. But thanks

Comment: @chanokim I'm pretty sure it's the version, redundant tags are just... well, redundant :) But glad it's solved.