# Application context from other maven module cannot be loaded

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have multi module maven project where each maven module has its own application context under `src/main/resources`. One of these multi module project is web application and application context of the application is importing application contexts of other maven modules. I am  using  similar pom configuration as it is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880305/changes-in-dependent-modules-cannot-be-seen-in-other-module-in-maven-eclipse) link.

My Problem is, application context of web application is unable to load application contexts of other maven modules, jars. I think it should be some how possible but i am unable to figure it. I have reconsidered application importing command with or without regex, but no success.

I would be highly thankful if you explain the aforementioned problem in light of an example.

Comment: How do you try tor load the application context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this all the time in multi-module Maven projects exactly as you describe. Just have e.g.

```
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/*.xml" />
```

in your webapps's application context and this will import all the Spring configuration under `/META-INF/spring` in all of its dependent modules. If not, maybe the modules concerned aren't declared as dependencies of the webapp?

Comment: I dont think you need to specify the `/META-INF/spring path`. All the modules imported using maven are loaded into the application classpath. So it should be sufficient to use `<import resource="classpath:*.xml" />`

Comment: @AxxAOsiris this doesn't work well, unfortunately, see [this explanation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-wildcards-in-path-other-stuff)

Comment: I have tried those tricks already " I have reconsidered application importing command with or without regex".

Comment: @Rehman well, like I say, the above definitely works as I've used it many times. If you need more help, you'll need to update your question with details such as your webapp and module project structure, POMs, and Spring context files.

Comment: i think your solution is absolutely right. Today i have figured out that i have something else to combat, persistence unit is not found.e.g.Thanks again

Comment: ouch.. can somebody explain why "classpath*:/META-INF/spring/*.xml" works but "classpath*:/META-INF/spring/*Context.xml" doesn't for importing file "someContext.xml"?