# Autowired dependencies in a Maven multi-module project

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc, m2e

I have a single Maven project that has the "core" and the "web" pieces in it. I'm attempting to convert it into multiple modules.

I've taken the "web" packages and put them into the new project. I've added the core project as a dependency and I can reference its classes within Eclipse. The "core" project correctly shows up in `WEB-INF\lib` in the "web" project when I build it.

The problem comes when classes from the "core" project are `@Autowired` in the "web" project.

In this particular case, I'm autowiring a service class from "core" into one of the web service classes in the "web" project. If I add the package that the core service is in to my `context:component-scan` in my "web" application config, it finds that service, but then the service references a repository, which references an entity, which is looking for an entity manager factory that I've got configured in my application-context in my "core" project.

So it seems that maybe the `context:component-scan` in the "core" project isn't happening maybe? Or maybe the classes that are picked up are not being made available to the "web" project?

I'm entirely new to multi-module projects, so if anyone can get me started in the right direction to resolve this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I'm using m2e in Eclipse with the Run Jetty Run plugin if that matters; however, I seem to have the same issues when I do a `mvn jetty:run` from the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to load the core module application-context from your web module application context. Otherwise it will not be aware of beans defined in the core application context.
Take a look the answers for [Application context from other maven module cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774606/application-context-from-other-maven-module-cannot-be-loaded) and [Spring import application context from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468195/spring-import-application-context-from-another-project) for proper solutions.
You can also have a look at this [post](http://blog.boehme.me/2012/06/multi-module-maven-project-with-spring.html) nicely describing how to create a multi-module Spring project using Maven.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems to work.  One more quick question if you don't mind... Is this the generally accepted solution to this type of modularization? The only reason I'm asking is because if I were to distribute my "core" project, someone would have to know at least the name of my application context in order to make it work properly. It's not an issue in my case because this is all internal, but I'd like to do it in the least fragile way. Is there a particular naming convention for application contexts that should be loaded in other modules?

Comment: Not sure if I would export my application context. It might be better to provide a good example of how to create such context with the main services exposed by your core library and let the consumer handle it. This, together with a clear documented API should do the trick in my opinion.